# Autoselect parent taxonomy if child is selected

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How can I have the parent taxonomy be automatically selected when one of its children gets selected? It would be a convenience if the parent is selected automatically in the backend for every child selected.

Right now, if I select a child and not the parent, then search or browse for the parent term, child terms under that parent are not brought back. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: Are you using Views ?

Comment: Not in this case. Display is routed to `page--taxonomy.tpl.php` for this instance.

Comment: This is about "term reference" fields and widgets. I think this will be useful to mention in the question.

Answer (score 1):

similar question here: [Check parent term when checking subterm](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27039/check-parent-term-when-checking-subterm/27421)

but if you need check all child when parent checked, you need some changes in JavaScript file

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Hierarchical Term Reference Autocomplete module](http://drupal.org/project/term_ref_autocomplete) and can accomplish the first half of the task.

For detail of how to use this module, go through the README.txt of the module.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 I recommend using [Term Reference Tree](http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree). It creates a hierarchical tree of taxonomy terms and allows you to toggle settings such as:

- Allow user to select only one term / allow multiple terms.
- Allow user to select only lowest-level terms / allow selection of parent terms.
- Record only the term lowest selection(s) / record all parent terms of selection(s).

This module is similar to [Taxonomy Tree Select module](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_tree_select) of Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this to only copy the root term over to another node. The rules module only have the parent value but how to drill down? This is what I did with Drupal 7.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function my_custom_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'my_custom_get_root_term' => array(
      'label' => t('Get root term'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'tid' => array(
          'type' => 'taxonomy_term',
          'label' => t('Term'),
        ),
      ),
      'provides' => array(
        'rootterm' => array(
          'type' => 'taxonomy_term',
          'label' => t('Root term'),
        )
      ),
      'group' => t('My custom rules'),
      'base' => 'my_custom_rules_action_get_root_term',
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Find the root term for the given $term.
 *
 * @param $term
 */
function my_custom_rules_action_get_root_term($term) {
  $results = drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  if (!is_object($term)) {
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($term);
  }
  if (empty($term)) {
    return;
  }

  // Build hash [$child] = $parent
  if (!isset($result[$term->tid])) {
    $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($term->vid);
    foreach ($tree as $tree_term) {
      // HUH: parents array always has one element on our vocabulary sets
      // No parent == 0
      $result = array_shift($tree_term->parents);
      echo $result . PHP_EOL;
      $results[$tree_term->tid] = $result;
    }
  }
  // follow the parent refs until $parent == 0
  $tid = $term->tid;
  while ($results[$tid] != 0) {
    $tid = $results[$tid];
  }
  return array('rootterm' => taxonomy_term_load($tid));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to do that is to use [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation (or a link) on how to do that with Rules ?