# Check parent term when checking subterm

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a client with a really large taxonomy, which is used for a certain node type. My client wants that the parent term of a chosen subterm, to also be used for a node.

Let's say that this is the taxonomy:

- Parent1

  - Child1
  - Child2
- Parent2

  - Child3

If the user checks (they are printed as checkboxes) either child, its parent term will also be used.

Is there already a module for that, or something, or do I have to write my own?

Drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) has this option.
install and select it as your taxonomy reference widget and check `Select parents automatically` in field instance setting form